# Promises and for loops - trying to validate multiple element text

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, chai

I am working on a function that will read the text of elements after using a filter feature. I have printed out the returned text and it is getting the elements, however I do not think I understand js promises.. activeFilters is a var I have already identified.

```
this.verifyColorFilterFunctional = function(color) {
    var bool = true;
    activeFilters.count().then(function (count) {
        var amt = count - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < amt; i++){
            activeFilters.get(i).getText().then(function(text) {
                bool = (color === text);
                console.log(bool);
            });
            if (!bool) {
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    return expect(bool).to.become(true);
};
```

The console.log prints out true and false as desired, however there are two things I have noticed. When false, it doesnt break like I told it to in the if statement. Also, I am getting a typeError: true is not a thenable error.. I believe the logic sounds good in my head but not to JS. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 2 problems here, firstly you can't use a standard for loop on an async method, and secondly you !bool is getting executed before you promise is even done.

Comment: My javascript is extremely weak... I tried to initialize variables in the promise and then use a for loop but the variables were not getting initialized

Comment: @Nico, there can be multiple elements to validate. the filter updates the results which I need to make sure out of all of those, however many display( say 9 or more) all have my desired filter.

Comment: I didn't write this comment as I want. Just delete it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protractor's `element.all()` supports getText() method which will return you the text displayed in the elements as an array.Then you can easily compare the resultant array using expect method.

```
this.verifyColorFilterFunctional = function(color) {
    activeFilters.getText().then(function (textArray) {
     expect(textArray).to.equal(Array(textArray.length-1).fill(color));
   });
}
```

Comment: Doesnt the getText() return a promise as well? This code did not work as well :(

Comment: yeah,getText() will return you the promise. but `expect` method will wait for the promise to resolve and then uses the result for the assertion. so what error are you getting when you tried the above solution?

Comment: Not sure that `.toEqual` will wait for the resolution. It would be simpler to to first resolve `activeFilters.getText().then(function (texts) {` and then assert against the expected array `expect(texts).toEqual(Array(texts.length - 1).fill(color));`

Comment: I am using chai so I changed toEqual to to.equal and it is an assertion error, meaning the comparison is coming back false. I believe maybe the text i am comparing is not the same.

Comment: Yeah, that will be simple. it should be `Array(texts.length - 1)` instead `Array(filters.length - 1)` i guess? @FlorentB.

Comment: @FlorentB can you post a code segment for what you are proposing?

Comment: @Tree55Topz, you should accept this answer since it's almost correct. Sudharsan Selvaraj can you fix it?

Comment: @FlorentB.Updated the answer. Thanks!!

Comment: @Florent, your suggestion worked once I used the .toString on the array and the texts. Thank you!

Comment: @Tree55Topz, this might be because of the `textArray.length-1` will never give the same number of items between the current array and expected array.